# Getting indentation error in time-series using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series

Getting indentation error while importing `csv` file.

My code is :

```
with open('C:/Users/miracle/Desktop/dnh/Sales Data.csv') as f:
        spamreader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in spamreader:
            print(row)
```

Comment: You would need to provide the error and probably a data sample for anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python will make you use indents as that is how it understands the code.

Try this

```
with open('C:/Users/miracle/Desktop/dnh/Sales Data.csv') as f: 
    spamreader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in spamreader: 
        print(row)
```

Comment: I used code as above but still there is an error

Comment: Try deleting any unwanted spaces and hidden characters in your code.

Comment: If I run with block seperately and by taking 10 rows then it is working but in the code the with block is giving errors like indentation.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your indents are correct:

```
with open('C:/Users/miracle/Desktop/dnh/Sales Data.csv') as f: 
     spamreader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in spamreader: 
         print(row)
```

Comment: yup, all my indents are correct. Even I get the same error

Comment: i would try unidenting everything and then retab/space each line.

Comment: If i am giving 10 rows then it is working but if I give large data set it is giving error...
Can you suggest how to remove null values in Tensorflow

Comment: what is causing the error, and what error are you getting?

Comment: If I use with block in code it is saying indentation error;
 with open("C:/Users/miracle/Desktop/ss.csv") as file:
                                                         ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation


If i use with block separately then it is working and also only with few rows....It is not taking csv file with large no.of records and which contain null values